# How to convert a Python Project into an exe program

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.3, pyinstaller, matplotlib-basemap

I have created a python mapping application, and the structure of the folder containing my code looks like the following:

> Data Feed Implementations(main folder)

Inside Data Feed Implementations:

> _ init _.py (folder)
>
> fp        (folder containing files downloaded from sourceforge for an external module named FeedParser)
>
> GetAtomFeed.py (class written by me  which is part of program)
>
> main.py (main script that takes user inputs and implements other classes)
>
> quakegui.py (class written by me  which is part of program)

The external module I installed called feedparser is an essential part of the project and is imported in GetAtomFeed, and GetAtomFeed is imported in main.py and quakegui.py. The program also uses matplotlib,plt and basemap.

How would i distribute this program so that the program can be run on a windows machine without python installed? I had a look at py2exe but it only supported python 2, and for the others such as pyinstaller it wasn't clear whether it would still create a standalone executable when external modules such as basemap (extension of matplotlib) and feedparser are used.